# I want my app to receive an sms to start the MainAcitivity. Even when the app is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have developed an app that receives a specific text message and then do a pre-defined task. This app works fine when it is running. but when it is closed it does not do the pre-defined task. I believe there is some problem that my app do not receive broadcast when it is closed. maybe i'm not properly registering the receiver in the manifest file.
I have two classes. one is **SMSReceiver** that extends the broadCast Receiver. and the second one is **MainActivity** that is calling the broadcast receiver to receive the text message and perform a specific task.

**My manifest file is:**

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:exported="true" 
android:enabled="true" android:directBootAware="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity

android:name=".MainActivity">

</activity>
```

**SMSReceiver Class Code:**

```
public class SMSReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
public String number;
public String nn;
public String v;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
}
```

**MainActivity class code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
public String r_num;
Button btn;
EditText msg;
EditText num;
IntentFilter intentFilter;

private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//MYCODE
}
}
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);
msg = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.message);
num = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.numbertxt);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
}} });
}

private void sendMsg(String n, String m) {
}

protected  void onResume()
{
registerReceiver(intentReceiver,intentFilter);
super.onResume();
}
protected void onPause()
{
unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
super.onPause();
}}
```

**This code works fine when my app is running. i want my app to respond to the message even when the app is closed/not running. Thanks in advance**

Comment: Use service for long running tasks. Service runs in the background.

Comment: I don't wanna use service as it can be stop by android os when memory is low. There should be other ways to do this. like registering the broadcast in maifest etc. please tell other ways

Comment: If `MainActivity` isn't running in the foreground when the text arrives, then it's not going to get the broadcast from your `SMSReceiver`, because its `BroadcastReceiver` won't be registered, and just won't do anything. If the task you're talking about is the `ACTION_CALL`, then you can do that directly in the Receiver (though it would be better to do the message processing and such in a `Service`, on a separate thread).

Comment: Yes you are right my MainAcitivity should run in the foreground when it receives the message. is it possible to do this without running a service?

Comment: You want to start your `MainActivity`, and initiate a phone call, both?

Comment: @EchoAsad yes is possible, but you need to think about the design. Your SMSReceiver (extending BroadcastReceiver) is the correct part, but you register it to listen to events in the activity, so basically it can listen only when the activity is foreground. If you want an activity without UI that always listen to events, well that's called Service in Android, and that's the way to go: use a service, and instantiate your SMSReceiver there. Note: Service(s) are handled differently on different Android versions, so be careful to handle them properly.

Comment: Ignore these comments about using a `Service` to receive SMS. It is unnecessary. You already have the Receiver for that correctly set up.

Comment: Also think about this part: "I don't wanna use service as it can be stop by android os when memory is low" ... seriously? In Android literally anything can be killed by the system at any point, even the whole process of your, and not only Services but also any Activity at any moment. Keep it or leave it, you need to deal with it, and the proper way is to follow the Android recommendations, not to refuse to deal with it, not to find workarounds (sorry, there are none), and not to fight against the system. Embrace the system instead.

Comment: You have two BroadcastReceivers. SMSReceiver which is statically registered in the manifest must work fine even if your app is closed. The second BroadcastReceiver which is registered dynamically won't work when your app is closed. Because you register it `onResume()` and unregister it `onPause()`.

Comment: Yes you are right @Bek . You Absolutely got my point. My second BroadcastReceiver is not working because i unregister it in onPause().  what should i do? please tell me. how can i make my second BroadcastReceiver  to work even if my app is closed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Waiting for your reply @Bek

Comment: why don't you start Call activity from SMSReceiver's broadcast?

Comment: there're multiple solutions depending on what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove broadcast receiver from MainActivity. In SMSReceiver's `onReceive()` start `MainActivity` instead sending broadcast. Put extra datas to intent and receive it in MainActivity's `onNewIntent()`.

```
Intent intent = Intent(context, MainActivity.java)
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

In `MainActivity` override `onNewIntent()`. Put broadcast receiver's code in MainActivity into `onNewIntent()`

Or put this code inside SMSReceiver instead sending broadcast.

```
if(v.equalsIgnoreCase("call.me")) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Generating Call, Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
    context.startActivity(callIntent);

}
```

put extras to intent from SMSReceiver like this

```
intent.putExtra("message", str);
intent.putExtra("me", v);
intent.putExtra("num", number);
```

receive it from `onNewIntent()` like this

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
String me = bundle.getString("me");
String number = bundle.getString("num");
```

Comment: This is the best answer. but i need more information please. can you pleasef tell me in detail how to pass some info (variables)   from SMSReceiver to MainAcitivty. and then how to receive the info in MainActivity.  I need the code

Comment: Thank you soo much @Bek. working in the SmsReceiver class worked for me. Thanks alot !!!!! :)